# Why can't I view json inside fetch's Response object in the developer console?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I recently learned about JavaScript's Fetch API, and am wondering why I cannot see json data directly from the Response object returned from the Fetch.

For example, I have a url that returns some json.

```
fetch("https://myURL/json",
    {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include"
    }
)
.then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(myJson) { 
  console.log(myJson); 
})
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the first `.then`, I can view the Response object returned from the fetch in Chrome/Firefox's developer console. That object will have some data, but no way to directly view the json. I have to call that object's `.json()` method and return that to actually see the json data.

Why can't I see the json data inside the Response object before calling `.json()`? Hasn't the Fetch finished when we reach the first `.then()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [this google developers article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)

> The response of a fetch() request is a Stream object, which means that when we call the json() method, a Promise is returned since the reading of the stream will happen asynchronously.

[MDN has some info on this as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you made a mistake while copy-pasting your code, but you are missing the closing quotes on the URL string.

Besides that, I tried that snippet of code and it does what it is supposed to do:

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include"
})
.then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9s9t2968/